# How to split Member Contribution page transactions to multiple financial types?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

On our Member Contribution Page, we have a price set with two fields.
1. Membership Choice - financial type 'Membership'
2. Donation Amount - financial type 'Donations'

Users pay, but the result is one contribution entered on the contacts record with the 'Membership' contribution type only (it appears).

Is there a way to get the donation to be recorded separately, or at least as its own financial type.

Larger question - best way to have Member Join/Renews and Donations on the same page, yet keep the books straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The data exists in Civi, but it's a bit tricky to get at.

When making a payment for a membership with additional donation the underlying database records a single contribution, but multiple "line items".  Each line item is recorded with the correct financial type, as described in the price set.  Oh yes - if you haven't enabled a price set on the contribution page in question, that's a required first step to setting different financial types on the different line items!  Though be careful if you offer auto-renewing memberships - there's a [bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17396) that can break your auto-renew functionality if you use a price set if you don't patch it first.

Once you have the price sets, with each field using its own financial type, you're in business!  CiviAccounts will export the data appropriately if you export data to your bookkeeping program.  You can also use the [Extended Reports](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) extension to run reports on line items rather than contributions.

The one missing piece of the puzzle is to search on financial type data instead of contribution data.  This doesn't exist currently in Civi.  Someone started to write it, but doesn't have funding to finish it; if you need that functionality, please reply to this in a comment, I've been trying to round up folks to crowdsource funding for this feature.

EDIT: There's some work afoot to get line item search crowdfunded for core CiviCRM.  Contact me if you're interested at http://palantetech.coop/contact.  Meanwhile, some of you might be interested in this [line item report extension](https://civicrm.org/blogs/jproffitt/announcing-the-line-item-report-extension).

Comment: Have just seen this. We'd be interested in contributing! Need the line item functionality, but our office search on contributions on a daily basis too.

Comment: On behalf of Carl Miller: I cannot add a comment to Jon G's answer so I guess I will go at it this way. Yes, I am looking for this capability to view line item financial types. We set up our Civi donations using pricesets so people could give to multiple funds and our staff could view donations based on fund accounts. At this point we need to give all staff full access since we cannot give restricted access using Smart groups and ACls.